# How to set div display value dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

How to display div dynamically through `javascript`?

Here is my code

```
var div = document.createElement("div");

var sBody = "<span style='background-color:#ffffc4;border:2px solid black;height:100%;width:100%;'>";

if (sLabel) {
    sBody += "<span style='font:10pt arial;font-weight:bold;padding-left:2px;text-align:center;width:100%;'>" + sLabel + "</span>";
}

sBody += "</span>";

div.innerHTML = sBody;
div.style.width = = iW;
div.style.height = iH;
div.style.display = 'inline';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please edit your question and format your code please?

Comment: So what is the actual problem you are having? Are you trying to make this new `div` appear within some other element within your page?

Comment: did u append the div in ur form ??

Answer (score 1):

Append ur div into ur form... u can have a form(or any element) with id="form1" for example, and append ur new div into this one.

```
var form = document.getElementById("form1");
form.appendChild(div);
```